# Where does this syntax come from in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Om2aEijfls#t=467) the unit testing with oUnit is presented. The test is defined by such a code snippet:

```
let test_fixture = "SimpleMath" >:::
[
    "add" >:: (fun () -> 
      assert_equal 4 (SimpleMath.add 2 2);
      assert_equal 0 (SimpleMath.add 0 0)
      );

    "subtract" >:: (fun () -> 
      assert_equal 4 (SimpleMath.subtract 9 3);
      assert_equal 3 (SimpleMath.subtract 5 2)
      )
 ]

let _ = run_test_tt test_fixture
```

Why are single semicolons used? I was taught in my classes that you always use the double semicolon for instructions. Why are we assigning the return value to the pattern? Is there any difference between `run_test_tt` and `run_test_tt_main`? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

From another example

```
let test1 test_ctxt = assert_equal "x" (Foo.unity "x");;
```

Why are we setting a type (!) as a function parameter?

Comment: OCaml type names and variable names can always be distinguished by context. So you can use type names as variable names, and in fact they often make pretty good variable names once you get used to this. E.g., "list" is a pretty good name for a generic list variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single semicolon is (in essence) an operator that combines two expressions by ignoring the value of the first expression and returning the value of the second expression.

In other words, for imperative code it acts like a semicolon in many other languages.

A double semicolon is a special symbol that tells the toplevel you want it to evaluate what you've typed so far. In my (humble) opinion, you should only use it when entering code into the top level. It has no real relation to the `;` operator.

There seems to be a fairly widespread misunderstanding that `;;` is some kind of important part of OCaml syntax. I don't think so; it's just a way of communicating with the toplevel (similar to, say, `#use` or `#show_module`).

**Update**

You ask whether you can write this:

```
let x = 4; print_int x
```

The answer is no, you can't write this. But this is because there's no previous value for `x`. This code is parsed as follows:

```
let x = (4; print_int x)
```

As you can see, this tries to print a previous value of `x`. The new `x` hasn't been bound yet when the `print_int` is evaluated.

The way to define local variables in OCaml is `let var = expr1 in expr2`. So you can just type `let x = 4 in print_int x`. (Personally I don't see why a semicolon would be preferable.)

You say your code doesn't parse if you remove `;;`. This can happen if you mix in imperative code at the top level of a module. My solution is simply not to do that. So instead of writing something like this in a module:

```
Print.printf "Welcome to module\n"
```

I write the following:

```
let () = Printf.printf "Welcome to module\n"
```

If your example were to appear at the top level of a module I would write this:

```
let x = 4
let () = print_int x
```

(Note, no semicolons at all!)

Also note that the code in your original posting is following this convention, except that they write `let _ = ...` instead of `let () = ...`.

Comment: So could I simply do `let x = 4; print_int x`? Or is it a bad practice? Besides, when I removed the double semicolon after a function, the code ceases to parse.

Comment: I'll update my answer to tackle these extra questions.

Comment: Thanks! This is my code which doesn't work without semicolons: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12789479/

Comment: This code does exactly what I was talking about. It has a bare function call at the outermost level. Since the call produces no output, it's not clear what it's supposed to be doing :-) Anyway you can replace it with `let _ = pow 2 5` and lose both of the `;;`.

Comment: I was just playing around ;) In interpreter it would output something, and I just copied the code to a file ;)